Is an algebra or a $\sigma$-algebra ？
Let $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ be a subset. The natural density is defined as
$$D(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap\{1,\cdots,n\}|}n$$
whenever this limit exists.
Define the family of sets $\mathscr{A}$:={$A\subset\mathbb{N}$; $A$ has a natural density}.
Is $\mathscr{A}$ an algebra or a $\sigma$-algebra ？

See Do the subsets of $\mathbb N$ that have asymptotic density form an algebra? AND If two sets have a natural (asymptotic) density, does their union? AND How to show CES is not an algebra AND Why is $\mathcal{A}$ not a $\sigma$-algebra? See also the accepted answer to Sets with no asymptotical density over $\mathbb N$.
